# I am Unable to extend the User model in Django

Tags: django

Here I have changed the model and view name but I am unable to extend my user model why it gives the error like Registration() got an unexpected keyword argument 'myuser' please try to solve this error.
And this problem arises many time  please give me the solution.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Registration(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dob=models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

class Candidate(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    total_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} -- {}".format(self.full_name,self.position)
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get the post parameters
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        dob   = request.POST['dob']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        # check for errorneous input
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This Aadhaar is Already Used')
            return redirect('home')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This Email is already Used')
            return redirect('home')
        if (pass1 != pass2):
            messages.error(request, " Passwords do not match")
            return redirect('home')

        # Create the user
        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        reg = Registration(dob=dob,myuser=myuser)
        reg.save()
        messages.success(request, "You are successfully registered")
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        return HttpResponse("404 - Not found")
```

error:

```
TypeError at /register
Registration() got an unexpected keyword argument 'myuser'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Registration() got an unexpected keyword argument 'myuser'
Exception Location: C:\Python3.9\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py, line 501, in __init__
Python Executable:  C:\Python3.9\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\DeLL\\PycharmProjects\\E_VotigSystem\\ovs',
 'C:\\Python3.9\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Python3.9\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python3.9\\lib',
 'C:\\Python3.9',
 'C:\\Python3.9\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 30 May 2021 12:30:11 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Registration model has a `user` field, you give it a `myuser`argument.

```
reg = Registration(dob=dob, user=myuser)
```

should fix it. But then again, fname and lname are not nullable.

Also, please be more verbose about your fields.

dob? fname? lname?

date_of_birth, first_name, last_name

Also, please finish the official tutorial, it has most of these things covered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Registration like `Registration(dob=dob, user=myuser)` because the field is named `user` in your Registration model - and you don’t need to call `reg.save()` the create step already persists the instance in your database - if you use `Registration.objects.create(dob=dob, user=myuser)`

Comment: so can i use user instead of myuser?

Comment: you have to use `user` as fieldname instead of `myuser`, because you named it user :)